# How to delete all the boxes in Hive Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am developing an application using Flutter; it will store some data locally, so I decided to use Hive package which was really amazing package to store data. So now I will store all the data locally when the user press the sync button. After that, if the user clicks sync again, I have to delete all the boxes and store data which may or may not have the same box name.
I don't want to increase the application storage to increase if the sync button is clicked, I want to delete all the boxes and again I want to create the box.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, then please share the answer.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [deleteFromDisk](https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/BoxBase/deleteFromDisk.html) method. It removes the file which contains the box and closes the box.

```
_myCourseBox.deleteFromDisk();
```

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, I don't think a feature to `clear()` all (opened, plus unopened) Hive boxes has been implemented. The box files are basically thrown into your device's application document directory as *.hive files (with compacted files as *.hivec and lock files as *.lock). There's no separate key-value store (or Hive box) that keeps track of previously created boxes, though you can implement such a Hive box yourself and iterate over those values as you please.

In your case, where you simply want to delete all the boxes in one sweep, a workaround could be to place all Hive boxes into a sub-directory (using `Hive.initFlutter('chosenPath')` ) and simply delete the directory when necessary using standard file operations. The only gotcha being that you call `Hive.close()` to close all open boxes before attempting this (to delete the undeletable *.lock files).

To simplify cross-platform references to the app's document directory you can use the *path_provider* package. Add `path_provider: ^1.6.5` to your dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`, and where necessary in your dart application `import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';` and `import 'dart:io';` for file operations;

Let's say you use `Hive.initFlutter('chosenPath')` to initialise and store your Hive.

So whenever you want to clear all boxes (after ensuring `Hive.close()` has been called), you could use the following code:

```
// Get the application's document directory    
var appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); 

// Get the chosen sub-directory for Hive files
var hiveDb = Directory('${appDir.path}/chosenPath');

// Delete the Hive directory and all its files
hiveDb.delete(recursive: true);
```

The directory will be re-generated from scratch the next time you call `Hive.initFlutter('chosenPath')`.

Comment: any suggestions for web?!

Answer (score 6):

You didn't share any code so I will just give an example.

I would suggest you to open the boxes in your main function

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(yourAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox('yourBoxName');
}
```

When user wants to sync, you can do following;

```
// It will delete all the entry in the box
Hive.box('yourBoxName').clear();
yourSyncOperation();
```

Comment: don't you need the await in front of that? `await box.clear();`

Comment: @LegitStack for multiple clear and inserting data `await` should be on front of that and then we should use `.then()`